# How to animate title bar (sliver) from left to center with a expandedHeight: 0?

Tags: flutter, animation, appbar, flutter-sliver, sliverappbar

I've tried scouring the Internet for a solution but every current available solution are with some expandedHeight.

I am looking for a solution to just move the title of a SliverAppBar to the center of the appbar upon scroll.

I wonder if AnimatedWidget should be used or is there a simpler solution?

Appreciate some examples and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

```
snap: false;
pinned: true;
floating: false;
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried the above, didn't really work. I read https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-sliverappbar-snap-those-headers-544e097248c0 seems like this solution need a flexible bar with expanded height too.